# Как передать данные в javascript функцию с помощью request?

Tags: python, requests, form

На сайте есть поле ввода и кнопка. При нажатии на кнопку происходит валидация и шифрование данных введенных в поле ввода и вывод диалогового окна на экран. На диалоговом окне есть текст и кнопка "Ок", при нажатии на которую происходит "POST" запрос. Всё это подчиняется javascript коду.

Как с помощью requests можно передать какие то данные в этот javascript код (обратиться к конкретной функции)? Возможно это можно реализовать с помощью библиотеки "requests-html ". Я использую Python, но мне подойдет материал на любом языке программирования.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-requests-python/poluchenie-otpravka-dannyh-vide-json/) почитайте (pyModuleDocs). Помог?

Comment: Очень мало информации, для того, что бы помочь Вам.  Подскажите, это ваш сайт или сторонний ? Бэк и фронт отдельно по принципу REST API ?

Comment: По сути js делает обработку html страницы. Вызвать его наверное будет сложно, единственный вариант, это если rest api и ваш сайт получает информацию из вашего бэк энда, вы можете реализовать запрос, который будет получать данные из веб формы  и возвращать результат. А в самом js файле, реализовать получение этого ответа и вставку его в эти поля.